# Changing Images onClick, also with time

Tags: javascript, html

There are pretty similar topics here, but I dont think any covers my question totally. So what I am trying to do in my home page is that, to have big image and 2 buttons, on the left and right (as arrows). I want 3-5 images to change in time, or when the arrows are clicked.

Pretty much a combination of these two : 
http://www.trivium.org/
http://www.airbournerock.com/

For the arrow part, I initially though storing the urls in an array, while keeping track of the index, and when ever the button is clicked, increment the index and change the src of the corresponding  tag with the url at the given index. But this seems a little "noobish".

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. I don't really see a problem or a question here, sorry. Maybe you show us what you have tried so far and come back with something which isn't working.

Comment: search `jQuery Carousel`

Comment: Try what you thought to do and then update your question with the progress you made and the issues you couldn't overcome.

Comment: You're basically trying to build an image slideshow. There's plenty of ones out there that already do what you're looking for. Take a look here: http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/web-development/jquery-slideshow/

Comment: Thanks Lucas, I didn't know what it was called, I want to build one myself, instead of using a plug-in. For those who weren't able to see a question, I literally had no idea, so I want to have an idea on how to start. Or general pseudo code/explanation on how those slideshows worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick jQuery solution.  The timing function at the bottom isn't going to work, but you get the general idea.

```
var image = [
'images/1.png',
'imgaes/2.png',
// ...
]; //create an array of <img> src's you have to add to this

var tot = image.length; //number of images in array
var c = 0; // current image (array key index)

function loadImage(){
  $("<img/>").attr({src:image[c]}).load(function() {
      $('#image').html( this ); //element you want the image loaded in
  }); 
}
loadImage(); // load 1 image

$('#prev, #next').click(function(){
  //you need to name some arrows with id="prev" and id="next"
  id= this.id==='next' ? c++ : c-- ;
  c= c==-1 ? tot-1 : c%tot ;
  loadImage(); 

});
//this isn't going to work, someone may have to help clean it up, but basically load new image every 3 seconds
setInterval(function(){
  c++;
  loadImage(); 
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man, I needed a general idea but I can try to analyse what is going on here =)

Comment: Make sure you're using jQuery if you use this answer.

Comment: Sure ! I won't use the code right away, it is more important to understand what is going on, for me. I will prob. use JS, so I will try integrate this idea into Js. Thanks again !

Comment: Cool.  I used that script recently for a project of my own, so thought I'd throw it up for you real quick.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it should help a lot !